# How to make auth.uid and database child key equal in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

What's happening here is that I have an app where users just can register if they are invited. By existing users, they need to fill out a form with the invited user's data, and e-mail address. Then these data will uploaded to the firebase database, with an unique generated key by .push(). Then an email is sent by the app to the specified email address, with an unique registration URL. It looks like this: `${host}/register/?uid=${keyGeneratedByPush}`. When the invited user clicks on the link, the browser will get the uid from the query string, and gets the data with it from the database. If everything goes well, the user clicks on submit and `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` gets called. The problem is the next: the auth() will generate an unique id (uid), but I already have an existing user id (generated by push). What I want to make them the same then if an user logs in, I can get the user.uid, and get the data from the database with it. A possible solution can be to get all the users, loop through them, and find the email address get by the user object, but why if we have ids. So how to make the two ids the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom authentication provider and use the push ID as your UID there.

But I recommend against doing that. I see the registration/invitation token in the invite as a different entity than the UID that you generate. While (depending on your use-case) there may be a 1:1 mapping between them, the values have different meanings. One identifies a specific invitation sent to a potential user, the other identifies a specific user.

I'd keep a list of the (pending) invitation tokens, and the email address they've been sent to. Then when the user clicks the link in the invitation, you can look up if it's the correct email address (if you care about that), and associate the eventual UID with the invitation code (if you care about that).